# Prevent a player from spamming a key in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently doing the tutorial learn with code from unity, in this section there are bonus challenges, that do not help you in resolving it. It says that i have to prevent the player from spamming the spacebar key to spawn dogs.
I am new to C#, i started to looking online but i see something about CoRoutines and i still dont know what that is, is there a simple way to do this, searching online i found something like this, but i cant make it work.
I also tried to make some conditional like canSpawn but i do not know how to implement it well, and Unity gives me an error that i cant use && between a bool and a keypress event

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    public float time = 2.0f;
    public float timer = Time.time;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer > time)
        {
            // On spacebar press, send dog
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                spawnDog();
            }
            timer = time;
    }

    void spawnDog()
    {
            Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close. One thing that might make it easier to understand the logic, is to just count up instead of trying to count down. So, in your case, the code would look like this:

```cs
void Update ( )
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if ( timer >= time )
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.Space ) )
        {
            spawnDog ( );
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}

void spawnDog ( )
{
    Instantiate ( dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation );
}
```

The `timer` keeps being added to, and when it's greater than your `time` value (in this case 2.0f), it allows you to press a key. ***IF*** a key is then pressed, the `timer` is reset to 0, and the player needs to wait `time` time (2.0f) before being able to press the space key again.

Answer (score 2):

I used Coroutines for this task, it has a little bit more code but it works nicely.

```cs
public class PlayerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    private bool isCoolDown = false;
    private float coolDown = 1f;

    private void Update( )
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (isCoolDown == false)
            {
                SpawnDog( );
                StartCoroutine(CoolDown( ));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CoolDown( )
    {
        isCoolDown = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(coolDown);
        isCoolDown = false;
    }

    private void SpawnDog( )
    {
         Instantiated(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using my phone. I am sorry if i made some syntax error.

```
bool isReadyForInstantiate;

void Start(){
    isReadyForInstantiate = true;
}

void Update(){
    if(isReadyForInstantiate && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        StartCoroutine(PreventSpam());
        Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

IEnumerator PreventSpam(){
    isReadyForInstantiate = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    isReadyForInstantiate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here my solution based on a StopWatch:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics; // hides UnityEngine.Debug. if needed use qualified call

public class PlayerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    public double dogDelayMillis = 2000d;

    private Stopwatch stopWatch;

    private void Start()
    {
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
            {
                if (stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > dogDelayMillis)
                {
                    stopWatch.Reset();
                    SpawnDog();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SpawnDog();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SpawnDog()
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
        Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example just for fun

```
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    [Range(0f,2f)]
    private float timer = 1.0f;
    private float waitTime = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Delay Input Timer - only execute the spacebar command if timer has caught up with waitTime
        if (timer < waitTime)
        {}
        // On spacebar press, send dog
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
            // Resets Timer
            timer = 0;
        }
        // Run Timer every frame
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log(timer);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck on the same exact thing, thank you. The code below is what I went with because it's short and sweet.

```
public GameObject dogPrefab;
[Range(0f,2f)]
private float timer = 1.0f;
private float waitTime = 1.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Delay Input Timer - only execute the spacebar command if timer has caught up with waitTime
    if (timer < waitTime)
    {}
    // On spacebar press, send dog
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
        // Resets Timer
        timer = 0;
    }
    // Run Timer every frame
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log(timer);
}
```

}